# Como enviar um objeto via Web service SOAP

Tags: java, web-service, ksoap2

Para enviar um dado primitivo é simples, porém quando se trata de dados complexos como o mostrado abaixo, uma exceção é lançada:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: Pessoa{nome=dado, endereco=dado etc...}

A maioria dos tutoriais e exemplos abordam o uso de tipos primitivos e não de tipos complexos como a questão aqui apresenta.

Dado um objeto representado abaixo:

```
public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private List<String> emails;
    private boolean ativo;

    // getters e setters

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Pessoa{nome="+dado+", endereco="+dado+" etc...}";
    }
}
```

Como enviá-lo para um serviço Web com o padrão SOAP utilizando a biblioteca kSOAP?

Comment: Bastante ampla esta questão, não? Me parece que o válido para o SOpt seria você fazer a implementação e postar aqui os problemas encontrados. Aparentemente kSOAP é mais utilizado em Android (http://www.emersonbarros.com.br/ksoap-2-consumindo-webservice-com-android/). É esta sua necessidade? Para outras necessidades eu sempre utilizei JAX-WS para webservices SOAP.

Comment: O seu link não supre a minha necessidade, pois preciso enviar tipos complexos, não primitivos. Mas vou dar uma melhorada na questão.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se esta é a resposta correta, pois não tenho como que testar o que você está fazendo. Mas vou tentar responder mesmo assim:

---

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: Pessoa{nome=dado, endereco=dado etc...}

Esta mensagem ocorre porque você tentou serializar uma pessoa e quando a exceção foi gerada, o método `toString()` da pessoa foi invocado para construir a mensagem de exceção.

Normalmente, objetos serializáveis implementam a interface `Serializable` e contém todos os campos serializáveis. Tipos primitivos são serializáveis, `String` é serializável. Se a classe que impleme o seu `List` for serializável (quase todas são, incluindo `ArrayList`) e todos os elementos da lista forem serializáveis então a lista por inteiro é serializável.

Portanto, talvez a sua solução seja apenas acrescentar o `implements Serializable` na definição da classe.

Comment: Fiz isso, mas a exceção ainda é lançada.

Comment: @williamhk2 Eu entendo a sua boa intenção ao melhorar a formatação do texto, mas no caso da mensagem de erro, ela é o resultado exato do método `toString()`, inclusive quaisquer eventuais erros de formatação, de gramática e de ortografia ou o que for. É importante que a mensagem de erro seja apresentada exatamente da forma como foi produzida, caso contrário ela não corresponderá com a verdade.

Comment: @Victor entendi, valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que implementar o Interface Serializable

```
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable
{
  public String name;
  public String address;
  public transient int SSN;
  public int number;

  public void mailCheck()
  {
     System.out.println("Mailing a check to " + name + " " + address);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não envia o objeto Pessoa por inteiro, o melhor seria criar um serializer do objeto.
Uma mensagem SOAP, nada mais é do que uma STRING com um formato XML seguindo alguns padrões diferentes.

Exemplo citado acima está no site: [serializer & deserializer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)